# Draw Figure as shown in this Image using Code

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone

I want to Draw Path as shown in the Image , which is geometric path or shapes, I want to draw path using C# code not Xaml. I tried to make Rectangle and Circle and overlap those Rectangles and circles but didn't work, I want to draw path giving the geometric values like,

Either by using Path figure class , 
I had used this code.

var path = new Path();
    path.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280");

but this code didn't work in windows phone 7. To be precise the the 
    Geometry.Parse did't work
but using C# code.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you *can* create this shape by adding and subtracting primitives (ellipses, rectangles, etc), for full flexibility, you are after the [`Path` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Using the values from your xaml example, it would look like this:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280");
```

However, you can combine `PathFigures` to create more advanced shapes programmatically.

Comment: the Geometry.Parse part didn't work in windows phone